# Can pointers be accessed globally in C?

Tags: c, pointers, scope

Can I access pointers from any function without sending info from `main()` to each function? I've tried looking for information but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: As long as the function can reach the pointer, either because pointer is global or passed as function variable, then yes.

Comment: A pointer is a variable like any other.  As such, it can only be accessed from other functions if it's a global, same as any other variable.

Comment: Can you? yes. should you? no.

Comment: Some sample code to show what you have a hard time understanding would really help. As it is the question is way too broad for anyone to help you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "access a pointer"; are you talking about using a pointer *variable* declared within `main` or elsewhere in the program, or are you talking about accessing a memory location directly (along the lines of `char *p = 0xDEADBEEF;`)?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try it?

Yes, you can, but [using lots of global variables is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/485020/106302).

Comment: It would be trivial to try it.  I can't understand why such questions are asked.

Answer (score 0):

If the pointer is passed to the function as parameter or it is declared as global then yes.

Comment: What do you mean by "passed by reference"? There are no references in C. Why does not ordinary pass-by-value suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, because address of variable - it's her own unique identifier in memory space, like a house address within the big city. And e.g. for debug reasons it can be very helpfull (the only thing you should be sure about - live scope of this variable, because when variable leaves her scope - pointer to this address is no longer valid).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said: There are good reasons to not use many globals ("locality of code" is useful), but careful use of globals is justified in some cases.  An example might help:

```
// A slightly contrived example to show how and when you 
// might use a global variable in a C program.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// The following are compile-time constants, and considered
// good coding practice
#define DEBUG_WARN 1
#define DEBUG_ERROR 2

// The following is a global, accessible from any function,
// and should be used cautiously.  Note the convention (not
// universally adopted) of prefixing its name with "g_"
int g_debug_threshold = 0;

// debug_print() uses the global variable to
// decide whether or not to print a debug message.
void debug_print(char *msg, int level) {
  if (level >= g_debug_threshold) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
  }
}

void foo() {
  debug_print("hi mom", DEBUG_WARN);
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  // Here we set the debug threshold at runtime
  if (ac > 1) {
    g_debug_threshold = atoi(av[1]);
  }
  foo();
}
```